# Macbook Air SMC reset

Tags: macos

I am trying to reset SMC, but I am not sure whether could I manage or not.

I pressed shift + option + control (left side) and power button at the same time but the indicator light didn't change and computer opened without pressing power button at second time.

Therefore, if I couldn't succeed, how can I do that ?

Macbook air 2015 early , OS X El Capitan

Answer (score 1):

It needs to be plugged into the mains to do it.

> **To reset the SMC:**
>
> 1. Shut down the computer.
> 2. Plug in the MagSafe or USB-C power adapter to a power source and to your computer.
> 3. On the built-in keyboard, press the (left side) Shift-Control-Option keys and the power button at the same time.
> 4. Release all the keys and the power button at the same time.
> 5. Press the power button to turn on the computer.

Source : Apple KB - [Resetting the System Management Controller (SMC) on your Mac](https://support.apple.com/HT201295)

Comment: But as your answer it says "Press the power button to turn on the computer." but when I try to reset smc I don't need to press power button again it opinion like normally after I press the buttons .For this reason ,I am asking whether am I succeed to reset smc or not .

Comment: Then you didn't succeed.

Comment: Then how can I succeed ?